# I set up UFW and now cant connect to server

Tags: server, ssh, ufw

I set up UFW and now I can't connect to my server anymore.

The terminal write:

```
ssh: connect to host 138.201.89.134 port 21: Connection refused
```

What should I do?

Comment: Please don't just enable something without first learning a bit about it!

Comment: Since you can't log in over SSH now, do you have any other way to change the server configuration? If not, you just locked yourself out of your own (virtual) machine. In that case try to contact the hoster because there's nothing you can do without their help.

Answer (score 4):

Did you allow incoming packages for port 21? Check with `sudo ufw status` to see if you have allowed packages transmission for port 21.

It will look something like that:

```
Firewall loaded

To                         Action    From
--                         ------    ----
21                         ALLOW IN  Anywhere
```

If port 21 is not allowed, enable the port by:

```
sudo ufw allow 21
```

Comment: This answer would work ....If the Op could connect.